# PDF created with puppeteer not showing font-awesome icons

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, puppeteer, webautomation

i need to create a PDF Buffer and save this to the database. I am passing the complete DOM to puppeteer and most of it works just fine. When i open the created PDF Buffer, bootstrap styles are applied and i get a beautifull PDF.

However, font-awesome icons will not show up. i have only two CSS files: framework.css (created with SASS and containing custom styles, bootstrap styles and font-awesome) and print-media (contains print media css to hide or show stuff like the navigation). Here is my Code to create the PDF Buffer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
      executablePath: pathToChrome}
);
const page = await browser.newPage();
const content = await page.setContent(pdfOptions.dom);
const addCss7 = await page.addStyleTag({path: appPath +  '/public/css/framework.css'});
const addCss8 = await page.addStyleTag({path: appPath +  '/public/css/print-media.css'});
const buffer = await page.pdf();
F.log(buffer);
```

Inside the css folder i created a fonts folder containing the font-awesome fonts and @font-face refers to this path:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0");
  src: url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0") format("woff2"), url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0") format("woff"), url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0") format("truetype"), url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Do i have to tell puppeteer that there are fonts it should use specifically or did i miss something else?

Thanks in advance,
Pascal

Edit:
Tried to use absolute path, but this will wont work either. If i do this, even the Website will not contain the fonts.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0");
    src: url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0") format("woff2"), url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0") format("woff"), url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0") format("truetype"), url("C:\Users\userFolder\someotherFolder\projectFolder\public\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try with headless false to see if the fonts are being applied in the page?

Comment: @hardkoded i just tried it. The icons are not loaded there as well.

Comment: I bet that the problem is in `"./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0"`. You have to think that If you call newPage and setContent, your root will be "about:blank" so it won't be able to find a "./fonts/"

Comment: yeah i think so as well, but how to tell chromium where to look?.

Comment: maybe you could publish that somewhere and target an absolute URL

Comment: i will try that later, thanks

Comment: @hardkoded tried with absolute paths still not working... see edit.

Comment: Could you try using a cdnjs url https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome ?

Comment: it works with cdn, but i have to use a downloaded version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented on the question. The problem is the `about:blank` location. What I recommend is doing the following:

- Create a `web` folder.
- Put there your fonts folder.
- Create there an empty.html file. Like this one https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/test/assets/empty.html
- After doing `const page = await browser.newPage();` call `await page.goto('file://your path/expressed/as/url/web/empty.html');`
- Now your relative path `"./fonts/`, should work

Comment: This will work if i run puppeteer with headless = false. But in my PDF, the icons will still not show :-( Thanks anway so far!

Comment: Hello again hardkoded, i just realized, in another context, that this works for SOME of the icons. Strangly enough, i got a 3 page PDF. The icons on the 2nd page are shown, but not on the 1st and 3rd one.
Thanks anway, it still helps a lot that at least some icons are there. If you have any idea why this behaviour occurs, please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by copying the specific fonts to my local filesystem fonts folder. On Mac OS I had to copy all Font Awesome fonts to `~/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: Hi Cory, i will try this. Just got back from my vacation, so i think i will not have the time for it until next week. will come back to you with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have embedded the font awesome css to the HTML header. It worked for me.

`<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>`.

I am feeding HTML content using setContent method but I can see icons on the HTML before including the above link, and I don't like the idea to rely on external css link.